# Exporting Scripts

Tags: testing, scripting, automated-tests, sharing, testcafe

I'm a freelancer and if I create the scripts in Test Cafe can they be ported to another application or repository?

I ask because if my client decides for me not to continue running their scripts they will want them back.

Thanks
Bret

Comment: I believe all tests created with the visual recorder can be converted to a .js file. So hence the answer is probably yes. Yes you can export your scripts to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

You can share test cases recorded in TestCafe Studio in the [.testcafe format](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401051/test-directory-structure/recorded-tests) or [convert them to JavaScript](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401052/test-directory-structure/test-scripts#convert-recorded-tests-to-javascript) as @user2675036 mentioned. However, test cases are specific to a particular application you are testing. Could you please clarify what you mean by 'porting test cases to another application'?